# How can I reset my Misfit Vapor X when it won't even boot after an automatic update?

Tags: boot-loop, android-wear

Okay, so I bought a Misfit Vapor X.  It was brand new, and worked for about an hour when it updated itself.  Now, it won't boot and goes into a boot loop when I try.

It will buzz, then show the Misfit logo for about ten seconds, and repeat the process.

I pressed the main button and the bottom button and got the watch to go into the recovery screen.

From there, I can choose:

- **START**
- **Shipping Mode**
- **Restart bootloader**
- **Recovery mode**
- **Power Off**

**START** goes into the boot loop

**Shipping Mode** gives me a screen of red letters that show this:

SHIPPING MODE
PPG Fail or Timeout!
LED1 3216, LED2 3832
IR 9003

**Recovery Mode** goes back into the boot loop

**Power Off** doesn't, and instead goes to the boot loop.

I googled the above cryptic message without any useful result.

I can't get ADB to see the watch (I'm not an expert, so I may not be doing that right...)

Comment: I would simply get the non-working watch back to the shop where you bought it.

Comment: @Robert -- Yeah, that's probably the only option.